# Input Hidden receber array do $.ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tenho um **$.ajax** que recebe do **PHP**

```
json_encode( array ($html, $relatoriosGr) );
```

Esse **return** do **$.ajax**, vai popular um **input hidden** com o **índice 1** do **result**:

```
success: function (result) {

                $("#dados").val(result[1]);

}
```

Isso ocorre *automaticamente*. Mas aí tem um problema: dá como valor vazio

Como solucionar esse problema?

```
json_encode( array ($html, $relatoriosGr) );
```

Não transforma tanto **$html** quanto **$relatoriosGr** em uma **string** jQuery?

Então porque o php **input** está **reclamando**?

Tentei fazer

```
echo array ( json_encode( $html), json_encode( $relatoriosGr) );
```

Mas dá o seguine erro:

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\wesleyanagceu.com.br\_scripts\_php\_buscas\relatorioCelulas.php</b> on line <b>80</b><br />
Array
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Objetivo**:

No pedaço de código anaixo:

```
<input type='hidden' id='dados' />
<button id='btnRelatorio' class='button'>Gerar Relatório</button>
<div class='dialog'></div>
```

Populo o **input hidden** com o resulado do **$.ajax** e disponibilizo seu **valor** para o **click** do **botão** `btnRelatorio` para outro **$.ajax**

Comment: então, se assim: json_encode( array ($html, $relatoriosGr) );, dá uma alert com valor vazio. Se assim echo array ( json_encode( $html), json_encode( $relatoriosGr) );, dá <b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\wesleyanagceu.com.br\_scripts\_php\_buscas\relatorioCelulas.php</b> on line <b>80</b><br />
Array

Comment: ué. mas é assim que está na pergunta. O indice 1 da jsom vem vazio

Comment: adicionado ao final da pergunta

Comment: <input type='hidden' id='dados' /> é porque vou usar o valor dele em um $.ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não se pode dar echo em Arrays, o comando echo é somente para Strings.

Tente com var_dump() ou print_r()

Comment: verdade, valeu.